# How to Install Eclipse Plugins Programmatically in a Dockerized Environment?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2, eclipse-jee

I am currently working on automating the setup of a complex development environment for a project that uses Eclipse as the primary IDE, including custom-built plugins. The goal is to containerize the entire development environment using Docker, which includes not only the Eclipse IDE but also pre-installing various plugins. We have successfully run the Eclipse IDE with GUI applications inside Docker using X11 on both Linux and Windows. However, I am encountering issues with pre-installing Eclipse plugins programmatically.

To install the plugins, I have attempted to use `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director` in headless mode. As an example, I tried to install the Subclipse SVN plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace. Here is the command I used:

```bash
eclipse -nosplash \
  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
  -repository https://subclipse.github.io/updates/subclipse/4.2.x/ \
  -installIU org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core \
  -installIU org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui \
  -installIU org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.graph \
  -installIU org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.mylyn \
  -installIU org.tmatesoft.svnkit \
  -installIU org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit \
  -installIU org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group \
  -installIU org.tmatesoft.svnkit.feature.group
```

The command executes without errors, and I can confirm that the JAR files for the plugins are present in the plugins directory of the Eclipse installation. However, when I start Eclipse and check the installed plugins for my default workspace, the newly installed plugins do not appear.

I'm seeking advice on what might be going wrong with this approach. Is there an additional step or flag required for the plugins to be recognized by a workspace when Eclipse is launched? Or perhaps there's a better method for pre-installing plugins in a Dockerized Eclipse environment?

Any insights or alternative methods for achieving this are greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: What you did should work, also with Docker. Did you run the p2 director and the Eclipse IDE as the same user (are the file permission of the installed plugins the same)? _"I start Eclipse and check the installed plugins for my default workspace"_ - how exactly did you do that (_Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_, tab _Plug-ins_)? By the way, the Eclipse Marketplace is just an catalog and not involved here; you installed the plugins directly from subclipse.github.io (`-repository ...`).

Comment: I didn't know about the About > Installation details. I'll check again and keep posted here. Thank you!

Comment: Please also show what the p2 director command prints. Maybe not everything is installed due missing requirements (in this case `-repository https://subclipse.github.io/updates/subclipse/4.2.x/,https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/` and/or specifying other p2 repositories might help).

Comment: There is a an example project on github creating a docker container
by provisioning java using osgi-starterkit and the included p2.director to install a docker container with eclipse product.
https://github.com/klibio/docker-eclipse